# same question but not quite

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, similarity

Okay, so I found a question over on stackoverflow which would appear to be the same on the surface:

[subversion merge - "has different repository root than"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601021/subversion-merge-has-different-repository-root-than)

But I know that the cause is different and need to find a solution... do I ask my own question, or is there some way of expanding on this users' question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to ask a new question with enough explanation of what the differences are to convince those who would question it.

Comment: This. Noting the similarity and stating clearly why you think there are different is the key to keeping your questions open. Well, that and it *really* being different.